# Django - MultiValueField Impementation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need a  MultiWidgets that renders HTML like following as a MultiValueField :

```
<div class="formfield_trailer">
  <div class="formfield_title">My Family</div>
  <select label="My Family" name="family_biodata[]" id="id_my_family_0">
    <option value="0">Select One</option>
    <option value="F">Father</option>
    <option value="M">Mother</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" size="5" class="family" label="My Parents" id="id_my_family" name="family_biodata[]">
  <input type="checkbox" label="My Family" name="family_biodata[]" id="id_my_family_2">
  <p><a>Add More<br><br></a></p>    
</div>
```

Thanks in advance. Also I Can any one help me for a detailed tutorial link regarding this as I am a newbie and Django Document doesn't specify much.

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: I was trying to populate a Select list a email text-box and a checkbox with a label beside it in a row. Also a Add More Link in the second line to replicate the fields below it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a project illustrating a MultiValueField example:

https://github.com/justinlilly/django_multiwidget_demo

Here's the relevant bit from that project's source:

```
# fields
from django.forms import fields
from djnycapp.widgets import AutoCompleteWidget
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserAutoCompleteField(fields.MultiValueField):
    widget = AutoCompleteWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Have to pass a list of field types to the constructor, else we
        won't get any data to our compress method.
        """
        all_fields = (
            fields.CharField(),
            fields.CharField(),
            )
        super(UserAutoCompleteField, self).__init__(all_fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        """
        Takes the values from the MultiWidget and passes them as a
        list to this function. This function needs to compress the
        list into a single object to save.
        """
        if data_list:
            return User.objects.get(id=data_list[0])
        return None
```

Comment: Sadly, at the time of writing the link is 404.

Comment: Aha that is a shame – here’s another example that includes the code for the widget subclass: https://gist.github.com/fish2000/5430868